# Android App hang( losing activity context) issue if open from background after long time?

Tags: android, android-context, android-memory, android-background

In my android application I have an issue in which if I open app from background after some time (2 or 3 hour) , that time my app got unresponsive. I have checked log cat regarding this and came to know that where ever I am using Context of activity (like storing value in shared preference , for progress dialog, setting typeface to text view) I am getting error . I am little sure that it is because I loose context of activity . Please suggest what to do in this situation . How can I save my context in case of memory leak . Or If memory leak occurs how my app can detect this? Also If I kill app and open from start it works normally. Thanks in advance .